# How to restore a dd partition image in a VDI having an empty MBR and a partition

Tags: linux, virtualbox, partitioning

I have a dd image of a partition that was /dev/sda1 on the original disk.

I need to create a VirtualBox machine out of it, on a VDI that should contain one partition /dev/sda1, and a MBR where to install GRUB boot loader.

VBoxManage seems to import it, it's readable, but it's an ext4 filesystem directly in /dev/sda, instead /dev/sda1.

What are the steps to end with a /dev/sda1 copy of the dd image and a MBR in the VDI?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on Linux, I'll outline the procedure there, using a raw image file for the VM:

1. Create a new image file which is slightly larger (a few sectors should be sufficient) than your existing dd image.
2. Loop-mount that image file. This will create a new block device, e.g. `/dev/loop0` (you may have to use something like `partx` or `partprobe` to make the new block device known to the kernel).
3. Partition the new image, e.g. using fdisk (something like `fdisk /dev/loop0`). Make sure that you make the size of the (only) partition exactly the size of the dd image you have.
4. Again, issue something like `partx` or `partprobe` to make the new partition known to the kernel. This will create a new block device, e.g. `/dev/loop0p1`, representing the new partition in the image file.
5. Copy the dd image you have into the new partition (e.g. `dd if=... of=/dev/loop0p1 bs=1M`).

Now you have a raw disk image file which contains a valid partition table and one partition with the exact contents of your original dd image, which is what you have asked for.

Of course, please don't forget to unmount the disk image before starting a VM which uses it.

The procedure would be basically the same for other disk image formats, provided you can somehow (loop-)mount that formats so that they can be represented by block devices. For example, this is possible with `qemu-nbd` and `qcow2`. I can't say anything about VirtualBox-specific formats, though, because I don't know VirtualBox.

Comment: qemu-nbd is one way to expose non-raw images (qcow, vhd, vdi, vmdk) as block devices, saving that extra conversion step.

Comment: I am absolutely null concerning this techique because I don't know loop - I will read about. For me, worked this one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41140/221551.

Comment: @user1686 You are right, it's `qemu-nbd`, not `qemu-img` - +1. Sorry for the typo. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @mike Then you obviously have a virtual disk with more than one partition, so you could boot the VM from one of them and dd the image into another one. The solution I outlined was assuming that you wanted only one partition in the virtual disk ...